# Gulp [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have read over several SO questions about this with no luck.

I'm trying to run Vue with Gulp and no webpack but I keep getting the error.
`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.` and `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`

My structure is:

```
project
|-- src
    |-- app
      |-- components
        -- app.vue
      |-- js
        -- main.js
      index.pug
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.1.5",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.1.9",
    "vue": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-pug": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-require-tasks": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.9",
    "vueify": "^9.2.4"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      "babelify"
    ],
    "browser": {
      "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common"
    }
  }
}
```

`javascript.js` (which is a task in my gulpfile)

```
var plugin = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
      camelize: true
  }),
  browserify = require('browserify'),
  babelify = require('babelify'),
  vueify = require('vueify'),
  source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
  paths = {
    js: 'src/app/js/main.js'
  };

module.exports = function( gulp, cb ) {
  return browserify({
    debug: true,
    entries: ['./src/app/js/main.js'],
  })
    .transform(babelify)
    .transform(vueify, {
      template: 'pug'
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
    .pipe(plugin.connect.reload())
    .on('error', function( error ) {
      console.error(String( error ));
    });
};
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './../components/app.vue'

new Vue({
  name: 'app',
  el: '#app'
}).$mount('#app');
```

`index.pug`

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    title Lexicon Riot
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width')
  body
    #app

    script(src='js/main.js')
```

`app.vue`

```
template
  div
    h1 {{ msg }}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion as to what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem when using webpack. The issue comes from the runtime version of Vue not providing that method, instead you need to use the standalone version. Then compile them before going to production.

I fixed this with adding

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  }
}
```

to my webpack.config.js

Info found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Standalone-vs-Runtime-only-Build

Comment: Sadly i've tried that as well and while it resolves the error nothing is rendered :/

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

So remove this part from `main.js`:

```
new Vue({
  name: 'app',
  el: '#app'
}).$mount('#app');
```

And put one I provided above.

Comment: So I get this error now, `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)`

Comment: Could you try to wrap everything into the `App.vue` with `div#app` and see does errors here ?

Comment: Hm, what if you change this `import App from './../components/app.vue'` to just this `import App from '../components/app.vue'`

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that in the `.vue` file I was using

```
template
```

instead of

```
<template>
```

So that in combination with the `webpack.config.js` solves my issue